# update multiple records in database using EF core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm new to EF i want to execute this sql command using only EF and linq  :

I looked on internet but most of the questions are related to old versions of EF

```
Update Foo set foo.Name ="Modified"
where Foo.id = 6
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as simple as following:

```
var foos = Foo.Where(f => f.id == 6).ToList();
foos.ForEach(f => f.Name = "Modified");

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: is this the only way to do it ? cant we do something to avoid hitting the database multiple times ( read + updates )

Comment: Here you hit the database once for a query and once for save data. This is the proper approach.